# Streaming video from RTSP source to a display using GStreamer in code results in "Internal data stream error", but works from command line?

Tags: c, video-streaming, gstreamer

IP addresses have been replaced by "" throughout this question.

I have created a GStreamer pipeline to stream video from an RTSP source to a display on SoM with an NXP processor with hardware decoder/encoder, using the following command line:

```
gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc latency=2 location="<address>" ! rtph264depay ! vpudec ! autovideosink
```

This pipeline works as I would want it to. However, when I try to write a program to replicate this, I come up against the following error:

```
====== VPUDEC: 4.7.2 build on Sep  1 2022 09:49:28. ======
    wrapper: 3.0.0 (VPUWRAPPER_ARM64_LINUX Build on Aug 31 2022 01:28:14)
    vpulib: 1.1.1
    firmware: 1.1.1.43691
Pipeline state changed from NULL to READY:
Pipeline state changed from READY to PAUSED:
Received new pad 'recv_rtp_src_0_1458973331_96' from 'source':
We are already linked. Ignoring.
Received new pad 'recv_rtp_src_1_2775117443_97' from 'source':
We are already linked. Ignoring.
Error received from element udpsrc2: Internal data stream error.
Debugging information: ../git/libs/gst/base/gstbasesrc.c(3127): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:test-pipeline/GstRTSPSrc:source/GstUDPSrc:udpsrc2:
streaming stopped, reason not-linked (-1)
```

I also get these errors as warnings when running the pipeline from the command line, but the stream is still displayed and appears to be unaffected.

When debugging, the number of pads associated with the source element is 0 throughout the program, although I am not sure what the number should be or even if that is an issue. Also, if I prevent my program terminating on this error and still allow it to run the video is still not displayed.

Following is my program:

```
#include <gst/gst.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct _CustomData
{
    GstElement *Pipeline;
    GstElement *Source;
    GstElement *Depay;
    GstElement *Decode;
    GstElement *Sink;
} CustomData;

void PadAddedHandler (GstElement *Src, GstPad *Pad, CustomData *Data);

void CreateElements (CustomData *Data);

void CreatePipeline (CustomData *Data);

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    CustomData Data;
    GstBus *Bus;
    GstMessage *Msg;
    GstStateChangeReturn Return;
    gboolean Terminate = FALSE;

    gst_init (&argc, &argv);

    /* Initial element creation. */

    CreateElements(&Data);
    if (!Data.Source || !Data.Depay || !Data.Decode || !Data.Sink)
    {
        g_printerr ("Not all elements could be created!\n");
        return -1;
    }

    CreatePipeline(&Data);
    if (!Data.Pipeline)
    {
        g_printerr ("Pipeline element could not be created!\n");
        return -1;
    }

    /* Build the pipeline. */

    gst_bin_add_many (GST_BIN (Data.Pipeline), Data.Source, Data.Depay, Data.Decode, Data.Sink, NULL);
    if (!gst_element_link_many (Data.Depay, Data.Decode, Data.Sink, NULL))
    {
        g_printerr ("Elements could not be linked\n");
        gst_object_unref (Data.Pipeline);
        return -1;
    }

    /* Set the source to the correct location. */

    g_object_set (Data.Source, "latency", 2, NULL);
    g_object_set (Data.Source, "location", "<address>", NULL);

    /* Connect to the pad-added signal. */

    g_signal_connect (Data.Source, "pad-added", G_CALLBACK (PadAddedHandler), &Data);

    /* Start playing. */

    Return = gst_element_set_state (Data.Pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
    if (Return == GST_STATE_CHANGE_FAILURE)
    {
        g_printerr ("Unable to set the pipeline to the playing state!\n");
        gst_object_unref (Data.Pipeline);
        return -1;
    }

    /* Listen to the bus. */
    Bus = gst_element_get_bus (Data.Pipeline);
    do {
        Msg = gst_bus_timed_pop_filtered (Bus, GST_CLOCK_TIME_NONE, GST_MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGED | GST_MESSAGE_ERROR | GST_MESSAGE_EOS);

        /* Parse message. */
        if (Msg != NULL)
        {
            GError *Error;
            gchar *DebugInfo;

            switch (GST_MESSAGE_TYPE (Msg))
            {
            case GST_MESSAGE_ERROR:
                gst_message_parse_error (Msg, &Error, &DebugInfo);
                g_printerr ("Error received from element %s: %s\n", GST_OBJECT_NAME (Msg->src), Error->message);
                g_printerr ("Debugging information: %s\n", DebugInfo ? DebugInfo : "none");
                g_clear_error (&Error);
                g_free (DebugInfo);
                Terminate = TRUE;
                break;
            case GST_MESSAGE_EOS:
                g_print ("End-Of-Stream message received.\n");
                Terminate = TRUE;
                break;
            case GST_MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGED:
                /* Ignore state-change messages from any element apart from the pipeline. */
                if (GST_MESSAGE_SRC (Msg) == GST_OBJECT (Data.Pipeline))
                {
                    GstState OldState;
                    GstState NewState;
                    GstState PendingState;
                    gst_message_parse_state_changed (Msg, &OldState, &NewState, &PendingState);
                    g_print ("Pipeline state changed from %s to %s:\n",
                            gst_element_state_get_name (OldState),
                            gst_element_state_get_name (NewState));
                }
                break;
            default:
                /* Any other unexpected messages. */
                g_printerr ("Unexpected error message received.\n");
                break;
            }
            gst_message_unref (Msg);

        }

    } while (!Terminate);

    /* Free resources. */
    gst_object_unref (Bus);
    gst_element_set_state (Data.Pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
    gst_object_unref (Data.Pipeline);



    return 0;
}



void PadAddedHandler (GstElement *Src, GstPad *NewPad, CustomData *Data)
{
    GstPad *SinkPad = gst_element_get_static_pad (Data->Decode, "sink");
    GstPadLinkReturn Return;
    GstCaps *NewPadCaps = NULL;
    GstStructure *NewPadStructure;
    const gchar *NewPadType = NULL;

    g_print ("Received new pad '%s' from '%s':\n", GST_PAD_NAME (NewPad), GST_ELEMENT_NAME (Src));

    /* If element is already linked, nothing to do. */
    if (gst_pad_is_linked (SinkPad))
    {
        g_print ("We are already linked. Ignoring.\n");
        goto exit;
    }

    /* Check new pad info. */
    NewPadCaps = gst_pad_get_current_caps (NewPad);
    NewPadStructure = gst_caps_get_structure (NewPadCaps, 0);
    NewPadType = gst_structure_get_name (NewPadStructure);

    /* Attempt the link. */
    Return = gst_pad_link (NewPad, SinkPad);
    if (GST_PAD_LINK_FAILED (Return))
    {
        g_print ("Type is '%s' but link failed!\n", NewPadType);
    } else {
        g_print ("Link succeeded (type '%s')!\n", NewPadType);
    }

exit:
    /* Unreference new pad's caps. */
    if (NewPadCaps != NULL)
    {
        gst_caps_unref (NewPadCaps);
    }
    /* Unreference sink pad. */
    gst_object_unref (SinkPad);
}



void CreateElements (CustomData *Data)
{
    Data->Source = gst_element_factory_make ("rtspsrc", "source");
    Data->Depay = gst_element_factory_make ("rtph264depay", "depay");
    Data->Decode = gst_element_factory_make ("vpudec", "decode");
    Data->Sink = gst_element_factory_make ("autovideosink", "sink");
}



void CreatePipeline (CustomData *Data)
{
    Data->Pipeline = gst_pipeline_new ("test-pipeline");
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas for how to fix this?